# QT : get the class name of an object

Tags: unit-testing, qt, classname, qtestlib

I'm writing a test app that simulates key presses of another application. For every key press I have to check if the right window/form is shown. So what I do is get the pointer of the window being shown and get it's window title. However, not all the windows/forms shown window titles. So I'm thinking it would be better to get the name of the class instead. How can I get the name of the class?

```
QWidget *pWin = QApplication::activeWindow();
```

when I try:

```
pWin->className();
```

to get the name of the class, I'm getting:

> "error: class QWidget has no member named 'className' "

Can somebody show me the right way?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Try using the  [metaobject](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#metaObject).

```
pWin->metaObject()->className();
```

Comment: When I try this I get the class name QObject which is the inherited class name and not the name of the derived class. Any comments on how to get the derived class name?

Comment: @DeanP You need to add the Q_OBJECT macro to your derived class in order for Qt to be aware of the derived class's name.

Answer (score 0):

You could also check the typeinfo header. Using the typeid operator on you object you get a type_info instance which describes the type of your object.
Check out: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/typeinfo/type_info/