# What is the parent of createEditor in a QStyledItemDelegate (PySide/PyQt/Qt)?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, qstyleditemdelegate

I have a `QTreeView` of a `QStandardItemModel`. I am painting/editing the data using a custom delegate. Within `createEditor` method, I use `parent.window()` to access the main window of the entire application (see below to link to some code from another question).

Question: what is the parent of `createEditor` in the delegate? It is defined with the following parameters:

```
def createEditor(self, parent, option, index)
```

What is confusing is when `QStyledItemDelegate` is initialized, and I print `type(parent)` for *that*, I get the tree back (the tree that I have made this delegate to display). This is what I expect. However, when I do the same and print `type(parent)` within `createEditor` method implementation, it just returns `QWidget`. I get the same when I run `parent.metaObject().className()` which is a suggestion I got from here:

[QT : get the class name of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241976/qt-get-the-class-name-of-an-object)

When I try to pull attributes that I've defined in the tree view, such as `parent.rootItem`, I get an attribute error. So, what is going on here? What is the parent of my editor?

I don't find much help from the [PyQt documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qstyleditemdelegate.html#createEditor):

> The parent argument, if not None, causes self to be owned by Qt
>   instead of PyQt. Reimplemented from
>   QAbstractItemDelegate.createEditor(). Returns the widget used to edit
>   the item specified by index for editing. The parent widget and style
>   option are used to control how the editor widget appears

Note this was all started by a solution to a different problem discussed in the comments to the solution here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32928091/1886357

Comment: Lordie I was deep in the thickets when I asked this question -- I wish I had known about `QProxyStyle`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parent is the [viewport widget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractscrollarea.html#viewport) of the view that is using the delegate. The viewport is part of the scrollarea that is inherited by the view.

So in your particular example:

```python
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        print(parent is parent.window().tree.viewport()) # True
```

Comment: Well....that is counterintuitive! I wonder why it is so hard to find this out using the normal type/meta tricks for finding what type of object you are working with....What is it scared of?

Comment: @neuronet. I suppose because it is an implementation detail. I think the viewport is set as the parent because that is the widget that receives the mouse and keyboard events